# How can I remove/delete ephemeral container from k8s pod

Tags: kubernetes

Since Kubernetes 1.25, the [ephemeral containers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug/debug-application/debug-running-pod/#ephemeral-container) are stable.

I can inject ephemeral container into running pod but when the purpose of debug container ends I'd like to remove the container from the pod but I still see it with Terminated state.

The docs currently say to delete the container I must delete whole pod similar to copied pod but I don't think that is right.

How can I delete ephemeral container from running pod without destroying it?

Comment: I tries to edit pod manifest interactively but got:

# * spec: Forbidden: pod updates may not change fields other than `spec.containers[*].image`, `spec.initContainers[*].image`, `spec.activeDeadlineSeconds`, `spec.tolerations` (only additions to existing tolerations) or `spec.terminationGracePeriodSeconds` (allow it to be set to 1 if it was previously negative)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately it isn't possible to do what you say.

> Ephemeral containers are created using a special *ephemeralcontainers* handler in the API rather than by adding them directly to *pod.spec*, so it's not possible to add an ephemeral container using *kubectl edit*.

> Like regular containers, you may not change or remove an ephemeral container after you have added it to a Pod.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/ephemeral-containers/#understanding-ephemeral-containers

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But I am not very happy about that. This behavior does not correspond with the meaning of ["ephemeral"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ephemeral) word.

Answer (score 0):

One option to remove the ephemeral `debug` containers would be to roll the deployment. It would create a new pod(s) without the ephemeral containers attached.

It will remove the running pod after the new one is scheduled but your service should remain available.

`kubectl rollout restart <deployment_name>`

Comment: Yes but that also removes the pod in question i.e. might cause service disrtuption.